# How to display title, description etc in block images?

Tags: plugins, filters, block-editor

I tried this code, but is not working, I just want to display the extra info from images when adding the block image.

```
// Function to add title, caption, and description to wp-block-image
function add_metadata_to_image_block($block_content, $block) {
    // Check if the block is of type wp-block-image
    if ($block['blockName'] === 'core/image') {
        // Get the block metadata
        $title = isset($block['attrs']['title']) ? $block['attrs']['title'] : '';
        $caption = isset($block['attrs']['caption']) ? $block['attrs']['caption'] : '';
    $description = isset($block['attrs']['description']) ? $block['attrs']['description'] : '';

    // Check if any of the metadata is not empty
    if (!empty($title) || !empty($caption) || !empty($description)) {
        // Find the <img> tag within the block content
        $pattern = '/<img([^>]*)>/';
        preg_match($pattern, $block_content, $matches);

        // Check if a match is found
        if (isset($matches[0])) {
            $img_tag = $matches[0];

            // Create a new div to wrap the content
            $new_content = '<div class="image-block-container">';

            // Add the original image
            $new_content .= $img_tag;

            // Add the title if it exists
            $new_content .= !empty($title) ? '<div class="image-title">' . $title . '</div>' : '';

            // Add the caption if it exists
            $new_content .= !empty($caption) ? '<div class="image-caption">' . $caption . '</div>' : '';

            // Add the description if it exists
            $new_content .= !empty($description) ? '<div class="image-description">' . $description . '</div>' : '';

            // Close the container div
            $new_content .= '</div>';

            // Replace the original <img> tag with the new content
            $block_content = str_replace($img_tag, $new_content, $block_content);
        }
    }
}

     return $block_content;
}
add_filter('render_block', 'add_metadata_to_image_block', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, did you check that title on image and caption are set in block editor? Caption shows by default anyway, so I don't see the reason to mangle block's code to add it once again. Description attribute does not exist on image block, so it must be added programmatically for that to even function: [a list of image blocks attributes]
(https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/core-blocks/#image). I think you took a code out of context, so it cannot work without the context it was in.

If you want to display title attribute, it can be done this way, but best way would be to extend default image react component by using [block hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/), however, this approach requires solid level of knowledge of react, so I guess it is too demanding to describe it here.

Code you pasted above should work, except for description attribute which does not exist.

In order to avoid this check `if ($block['blockName'] === 'core/image')`, you could also use [this filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/render_block_this-name/).

EDIT:
There is a new HTML API, you can as well check it, perhaps this could also help you in your development: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/03/07/introducing-the-html-api-in-wordpress-6-2/

Comment: Yes, the image has all the available fields filled in - title, alt text, and description. However, the description doesn't actually come in the block code by default as you pointed :(